# How to generate sequence numbers in ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I want to generate sequence numbers in sssrs report as given in following image.

[image]

Is it possible to generate these numbers in ssrs report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially add a column to your table which will store the calculation of the row number and make it hidden

You can use RunningValue with DistinctCount for each group in order to get the group number.

The expression will be like those below (heading, group, category, title)

```
= RunningValue(Fields!heading.Value, CountDistinct, "DataSet1")
= RunningValue(Fields!groups.Value, CountDistinct, "table1_Group1")
= RunningValue(Fields!category.Value, CountDistinct, "table1_Group2")
= RunningValue(Fields!title.Value, CountDistinct, "table1_Group3")
```

Your number column expression will look like those below (textbox1 contains the row number for heading, textbox16 for groups, ...)

```
= ReportItems!textbox1.value
= Reportitems!textbox1.Value & "." & Reportitems!textbox16.Value
= Reportitems!textbox1.Value & "." & Reportitems!textbox16.Value & "." & Reportitems!textbox22.Value
= Reportitems!textbox1.Value & "." & Reportitems!textbox16.Value & "." & Reportitems!textbox22.Value & "." & Reportitems!textbox4.Value
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: = RunningValue(Fields!heading.Value, CountDistinct, "DataSet1")
= RunningValue(Fields!groups.Value, CountDistinct, "table1_Group1")  here "Dataset1" and "table1_Group1" are two different dataset?    My data is in single dataset

Comment: There are no different datasets, but beside the first one these are grouping names

Answer (score 0):

You can insert in `RowNumber(Nothing)` in each group header. Hope it helps.

Reference: How to add it each group header - http://www.sqlcircuit.com/2013/08/ssrs-how-to-implement-alternate.html